# Does the ordering of contents in LEGO advent calendars vary between specimens?

Tags: advent-calendar

In general, LEGO advent calendars are boxes where for each day, there is a small model, or sometimes a minifig, hidden behind the window. Some superficial instructions on how to assemble the model are printed on the inside of the window lid.

Now, in general, the exact content of an advent calendar is supposed to be somewhat of a surprise to the one opening the window. While for LEGO advent calendars, all minifigs and models are contained somewhere on the imagery that decorates the outside of the calendar, I wonder whether at least the ordering is a bit of a surprise.

Or, in other words: If I bought the same LEGO advent calendar twice, would there be a chance that the content were ordered differently? (The box art on [the 2019 city calendar](https://brickset.com/sets/60235-1/City-Advent-Calendar) weakly implies the answer might be *yes*, given that the example on the back side shows some open windows with their content, and said content was due on different days in our own copy.)

Thus: **Are there differently ordered versions of these advent calendars? Are they somehow randomized, or is there just a handful of different sorting patterns? Even if so, are there any windows/days that always have the same content (e.g. day 24)?**

Comment: Bricklink lists the items as minisets per day: https://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemInv.asp?S=60235-1&viewItemType=S

Comment: @MichaelVerschaeve: I think that listing might form a good core for an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No. The ordering is always the same.

If it wasn't there probably wouldn't be daily reviews of today's gift(s) on sites like Brickset.

Comment: I don't quite understand the second paragraph. I'm not suggesting the overall content of the calendar changes.

Comment: But it would be pointless to post a description of today's content if everybody didn't get the same. And some might find the last part of the calendar spoiled if they could see everywhere what the remaining gift were.

Comment: I'm utterly confused now. Or wait, are you saying there *are* daily reviews of today's gifts? In that case, in the answer, did you maybe mean "wouldn't" instead of "would"? That would make sense (and linking to a couple of these reviews that discuss the same gifts on the same day would make the answer even stronger in that case).

Comment: As for finding part of the calendar spoiled - well, as the box art on the outside of the calendar already shows all the gifts, that would seem like a minor concern.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper "Or wait, are you saying there are daily reviews of today's gifts?" Yes, there are daily reviews of all four advent calendars: [City](https://brickset.com/article/47190/city-advent-calendar-day-16), [Friends](https://brickset.com/article/47274/friends-advent-calendar-day-16), [Harry Potter](https://brickset.com/article/47214/harry-potter-advent-calendar-day-16) and [Star Wars](https://brickset.com/article/47238/star-wars-advent-calendar-day-16). There were some reviews of an old [Clikits calendar](https://brickset.com/article/47254/clikits-advent-calendar-day-8) as well.

Comment: Sorry for that typo, and for not catching it, when @O.R.Mapper first questioned that paragraph.